Prove that $f(x+y) = g(x)-y$ cannot exist
From Spivak's Calculus (p. 50) :
Let the following functions be defined as $$f(x+y) = g(x) - y$$ For all $x, y \in  ℝ.$ Prove that such functions cannot exist.
My attempt:
My intuition says I need to play around plugging different values for $x$ and $y$ until I find a contradiction.
$f(x+0) = g(x) - 0 \implies f(x) = g(x)$
$f(0+x) = g(0) - x \implies f(x) = g(0) - x$
Couldn't get anything from this doing algebraic manipulations alone and eventually halted here. I believe there is a silly thing I am overlooking or perhaps that is not how this problem should be attacked at all.

noting about $f$ or $g$ ? And which function can't exist ? $f$ or $g$ ?

If $g(x)=-x$, then we can define $f(x)=-x$ too, and we get $f(x+y)=g(x)-y=-x-y$ for all $x,y$. So your question is missing something,

Just edited. Exercise says to prove that both $f$ and $g$ do not exist.

Right, but the previous comment shows they do.

$$
\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) = \operatorname{g}\left(x\right) = -x
$$

Maybe the question has a part with $f(x)≠g(x)≠-x$

I looked up the question, and you wrote it correctly. I believe it's a typo in the question. Not sure if it's corrected in other editions.

I have verified that the post is accurate, so it seems there was a typo in the book, since there are in fact functions that satisfy the proposed relation.
As you noted, by setting $y=0$, you can show that the two functions coincide, $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x$. By setting $x=0$, you find that $f(y) = g(0) - y = f(0) - y$ for all $y$. Using this last expression for $f$ (and $g$), you can see that the relation holds.
Therefore, there are infinitely many functions that satisfy the proposed relation, specifically any function of the form $f(x) = a - x$.


@Doug Given two functions $f,g$ we can check if the relation is satisfied (or not) for every $x, y$. Choosing $f(x)=g(x)=a -x$ yields the relation true.

In such(asymmetric) functional equations, a useful method that can be used is substitute $y$ in place $x$ and vice-versa, then compare both the equations so obtained. In your question:
$$f(x+y) = g(x) - y$$
$$f(x+y) = g(y) - x$$
$$\implies g(x) - y=g(y) - x$$
$$\implies g(x) + x=g(y) + y$$
$\because$ The above equation holds true $\forall x,y\in R$, $g(x)-x$ must be constant:
$$g(x)=-x+g(0)$$
$$\implies f(x+y)=g(0)-x-y$$
From observation or by equating either $x$ or $y$ to $0$ in the above equation yields:
$$\therefore \boxed{f(x)=g(x)=g(0)-x}$$
Verification:
$$g(x)-y=g(0)-x-y=g(0)-(x+y)=f(x+y)$$
Hence, the functional equation is indeed correct and its solutions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do exist, so it's likely that there is a typo in the question.
